# NLB or HAProxy - Better way to perform SSL termination?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, amazon-eks, haproxy, aws-nlb

My architecture looks like this:

[image]

Here, the HTTPS requests first go to the route53 service for DNS resolution. Route53 forwards the request to the [Network Load balancer](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/nlb/). This service redirects the traffic to HAProxy pods running inside a Kubernetes cluster.

The HAProxy servers are required to read a specific request header and based on its value, it will route the traffic to backend. To keep things simple, I have kept a single K8 Backend cluster, but assume that there are more than 1 such backend cluster running.

Considering this architecture:

- What is the best place to perform [TLS termination](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)? Should we do it at NLB (green box) or implement it at HAProxy (Orange box)?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages of each scenario?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the NLB you can achieve **End to end** HTTPS also however it forces the service also to use.

You can terminate at the LB level if you have multiple **LB** backed by clusters, leveraging the **AWS cert manage** with **LB** will be an easy way to manage the multiple setups.

There is no guarantee that if anyone that enters in your network won't be able to exploit a bug capable of intercepting traffic between services, Software Defined Network(SDN) in your VPC is secure and protects from spoofing but no guarantee.

So there is an advantage if you use **TLS/SSL** inside the VPC also.